# Cordova 3.6.3 for Phonegap CLI 3.5.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I am having Phonegap CLI 3.5.0-0.21.18, when i navigate down to cordova inside this CLI and execute the command "cordova -v" it return 3.5.0-0.2.7. HOw can i get cordova 3.6.3 for the Phonegap CLI 3.5.0 ? or is there any Phonegap CLI with latest cordova ? Please help me to get the latest Phonegap CLI with latest cordova.

Thanks
Swapna

Answer (score 1):

update your cordova

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: i donot have a separate cordova installation.